# Cloud Run: image [name] not found even image does exist in container registry

Tags: google-cloud-run, google-cloud-registry

I try to run my image on Cloud Run but it said:

[image: Cloud Run message]

yaml:

[image]

Anyway my image does exist in the Container Registry
[image]

I try to run that container above with specific tag or Digest but it still doesn't work.

Do we have the way to solve this kind of problem?

Comment: How do you deploy your service? With the console? With the CLI?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I have deployed using cloud console.

Comment: Very strange... Did you try with the command line? It could be a UI bug!

Comment: Is the Container Registry in the same Project as the Cloud Run Service or a different one?

Comment: @BenK Container registry is in the same project as Cloud run.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I already try using gcloud command but it still the same.

Comment: One thing I noted, I built that container using Jib, than run with Cloud Run and it show image not found, I've pull that image to run on local pc and my server but it still work fine. So I created new build using Dockerfile and this time it works with Cloud Run. I'm sure my Jib container doesn't have any problem, I already run it in my production environment nearly one year.

Comment: If you can pull the same image from GCR, the container packager tool isn't the issue (JIB or Docker). There is something between cloud run and GCR. Can you try, on GCR to add another tag on your image and use it instead of SHA? Or use the latest version explicitaly?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Like I mentioned above, I have tried both ways using tag or specific SHA, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: I have found the exact issue here. I built image using Jib and set image format to OCI that is why image not found by Cloud Run. If I omit the format option, then it works fine.